# jQuery fadein not working for me

Tags: jquery, fadein

At [this site](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/), there is a "subscribe" button on the top right hand corner of the screen.

When I click this img, the following divs (just above the closing `<body>` tag):

```
<div id="mailchimp-rossnorth">
    <div class="mailchimp-form">
```

should fade in, but they don't.

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/krztd2yr/).

For the subscribe img, I have:

```
<div id="subscribe_slideoutTab">
    <a href="#" id="btn-subscribe"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/subscribe.png" alt="subscribe to our newsletter" title="subscribe to our newsletter" border="0" /></a>
</div>
```

In the header, I have:

```
<script>
    jQuery('#btn-subscribe').on('click', function () {
        jQuery('#mailchimp-rossnorth').fadeIn(500);
        jQuery('.mailchimp-form').fadeIn(500);
    });
</script>
```

In the footer, I have:

```
<div id="mailchimp-rossnorth">
    <div class="mailchimp-form">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us11.list-manage.com","uuid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","lid":"xxxxxxx"}) })</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS, I have:

```
#subscribe_slideoutTab {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 75px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#mailchimp-rossnorth {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #000;
    opacity    : 0.6;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index    : 9998;
    display    : none;      
}
.mailchimp-form {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 9999;
    display  : none;
}
```

jQuery is included, so I can't find out what is causing this problem.

Can you see what is preventing the

```
<div id="mailchimp-rossnorth">
    <div class="mailchimp-form">
```

from showing?

**Update:** Please check [this development page](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/).

Comment: so many errors are shown in your site

Comment: Sorry. I had saved a website and uploaded it to a test URL, and in the process, `*.js` became `*.js.download`. Fixed now @Mark.

Comment: in jsfiddle, it is working fine? https://jsfiddle.net/krztd2yr/2/    in your jsfiddle, it isnt working just because you didnt include JQUERY

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Added jQuery to the jsFiddle, and it worked fine. Question becomes: why won't the jQuery work on production site?

Comment: JsFiddle that you have added, is missing the JQuery. I added that, it started to work. Can you recheck and reconfirm the issue? And on your production site, JQuery path seems to be wrong. Its throwing 404. Looking at following path: http://test.doig.com.au/jquery.js (check firebug network)

Comment: @MilanChheda I've updated the development page to [this page](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/) which has far less console errors.

Comment: Hm Ok. You want us to help you out resole those console errors?

Comment: Yes please @MilanChheda. Actually, they're fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

I'm getting a "jQuery is not defined" error when viewing your website. You are including jquery in the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./index_files/jquery.js"></script>
```

But when I tried accessing that URL I reached got a 404 error. You need to make sure your jquery.js file exists in that URL or change the src attribute to the correct location.

Comment: Apologies. I've edited the index.html and renamed *.js.download to *.js. jQuery is now accessible.

Comment: I've updated the development page to [this page](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/)

Comment: Console errors fixed, and jQuery confirmed as loaded.

Comment: You still have some console errors. Right now markerwithlabel.js is returning an error because the google variable is being used before it is define on line 84. Please understand that javascript terminates if there are errors. This means that any script you wrote after that error will not be executed. Your script needs to be error-free.

Comment: Hi Nadav. I have cleared the console errors. Issue remains.

Comment: No roundtrip.js is still throwing you an error. As I wrote before - once those errors are taken care of your script will work. The fadein script is correct. The errors in your website just prevents it from working.

Comment: I am logged into Wordpress admin. I don't see any console errors on the front end, yet the script is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is working fine. You need to tell JSFiddle to use the JQuery library in the settings wheel. Look in the JavaScript box for the word "JAVASCRIPT" and next to it there is a cog. Click the cog and select the JQuery library, 2.x.x version. If you do that your subscribe button works. I clicked and things faded in. Your JQuery is fine. The site you linked to has a TON of errors. Fix the JS errors or remove those scripts and this should work as expected.

Comment: Please check [this page](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/) as the development page.

Comment: Console errors have been removed from [the site](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/).

Answer (score 0):

I added the external jquery lib file.

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

Its working fine.

Please check the jsfiddle. in external link you need to add `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

`https://jsfiddle.net/krztd2yr/`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in your JsFiddle when you add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

in your html code
You are missing Jquery file in your code
Updated: 
[image]

This is testing in your development site.

Comment: Hi Zaw. Jquery is added at [this site](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/) yet the code does not work properly there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for you:

```js
jQuery('#btn-subscribe').on('click', function () {
  $('#mailchimp-rossnorth').fadeIn(500);
  $('.mailchimp-form').fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
#subscribe_slideoutTab {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 75px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
 z-index: 9999;
 background-color: transparent;
}
#mailchimp-rossnorth {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #000;
    opacity    : 0.6;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index    : 9998;
    display    : none;  
}
.mailchimp-form {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 9999;
    display  : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="subscribe_slideoutTab">
 <img src="http://test.doig.com.au/rossnorth/index_files/subscribe.png" alt="subscribe to our newsletter" title="subscribe to our newsletter" border="0" id="btn-subscribe" data-pin-nopin="true">
</div>
<div id="mailchimp-rossnorth">
 <div class="mailchimp-form">
    text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Milan. The problem is that this code does not work on [my site](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/).

Comment: Well, on your site there are lot of JS and stuffs getting loaded. Might be some conflict or something missing. Will need to review that. As for the mentioned code above that you requested for, it works here. We can definitely look at your site separately. Meanwhile, you can vote and close this question.